# SQL Find Gaps in ranges with exclusions and regroup them as new ranges

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have two SQL tables.

One contains the file information say Table1

Second contains record of print say Table2

```
**Table1**
File_name  TotalPages
====================
A            50
B            75
C            50

**Table2**
File_name from_page to_page
============================
A          13          15
A          21          30
B          13          13
A          41          41
```

The requirement is to display ranges of pending pages in the file whenever the user select the file.

For e.g.:

The user should see the below table say table3 when user wants to see pending record of file_name A

```
File_name from_page to_page
===========================
A          1          12
A          16          20
A          30          40
A          42          50
```

I read the below SQL Gaps and Island but couldn't find a way.

[SQL Gaps and Islands](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)

Comment: "I have tried multiple CTE and SQL Gaps and Island" Please show what you tried and why it didn't work. Also, mysql <> sql server, please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: For the below table

lt_bil_4678_01_201801_e_a4_old_1.pdf|7|15
lt_bil_4678_01_201801_e_a4_old_1.pdf|16|338

I am getting the output wrong as:
1|6
16|15
339|338

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query needs SQL 2012 or higher version. IF you have lower version use `row_number` to order `@Table2` and join with next row.

```
declare @Table1 table (
    File_name char(1)
    , TotalPages int
)

declare @Table2 table (
    File_name char(1)
    , from_page int
    , to_page int
)

insert into @Table1
values 
    ('A', 50)
    ,('B', 75)
    ,('C', 50)


insert into @Table2
values 
    ('A', 13, 15)
    ,('A', 21, 30)
    ,('B', 13, 13)
    ,('A', 41, 41)

select
    File_name, from_page = to_page + 1
    , to_page = next_row - iif(TotalPages = next_row, 0, 1)
from (
    select
        a.*, b.TotalPages
        , next_row = isnull(lead(a.from_page) over (partition by a.File_name order by a.from_page), b.TotalPages)
    from
        @Table2 a
        join @Table1 b on a.File_name = b.File_name
) t
where
    next_row - to_page > 1
union all
select
    File_name, 1, min(from_page) - 1
from
    @Table2
group by File_name
having min(from_page) > 1
order by 1, 2
```

Output:

```
File_name    from_page    to_page
---------------------------------
A            1            12
A            16           20
A            31           40
A            42           50
B            1            12
B            14           75
```

Edit:
Something like this should work:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        *, rn = row_number() over (partition by File_name order by from_page)
    from
        @Table2
)

select
    File_name, from_page = to_page + 1
    , to_page = next_row - iif(TotalPages = next_row, 0, 1)
from (
    select
        a.*, c.TotalPages
        , next_row = isnull(b.from_page, c.TotalPages)
    from
        cte a
        left join cte b on a.File_name = b.File_name and a.rn + 1 = b.rn
        join @Table1 c on a.File_name = c.File_name
) t
where
    next_row - to_page > 1
union all
select
    File_name, 1, min(from_page) - 1
from
    @Table2
group by File_name
having min(from_page) > 1
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: For the below table

lt_bil_4678_01_201801_e_a4_old_1.pdf|7|15
lt_bil_4678_01_201801_e_a4_old_1.pdf|16|338

I am getting the output wrong as:
1|6
16|15
339|338

Comment: I achieved the same via cte looked cleaner: `with get_pages(from_pages,to_pages)
as
(
select
    from_page = a.pdf_to_page + 1
    ,to_page = isnull(lead(a.from_page) over (partition by a.file_name order by a.from_page), b.pdf_pages + 1) - 1
from
    Print_records a
    join Print_table_Main b on a.file_name = b.file_name
 where a.file_n=@file_n and b.file_n=@file_n
union all
select
    1, min(from_page) - 1
from
    Print_records
where file_n=@file_n
group by file_n
having min(from_page) > 1
)
select * from get_pages where from_pages<=to_pages order by 1, 2`

Comment: can you show me an example with row_number as the deployment server is SQL server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to create one reference table which have numbers from 1 to max no of pages into you file. and update this table to achieve your result. below is the sample code -

```
            create table Table1 (File_name char(1) ,TotalPages int)

        insert into Table1
        select  'A' , 50
        union
        select 'B',75
        union
        select 'C',50


    create table Table2 (File_name char(1) ,from_page int , to_page int )

    insert into Table2
    select  'A' , 13,15
    union
    select 'A',21,30
    union
select 'B',13,13
union
select 'A',41,41    
 go

if exists ( select OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Ref'))
begin
 drop table #Ref
end 

create table #Ref(i int , IsValue int , FileName char(1))

declare @File_name char(1) , @TotalPages int , @pagecount int

set @File_name = 'A' -------------<<< set your file name

select @TotalPages = TotalPages , @pagecount = 1 from Table1 

while (@pagecount <= @TotalPages)
begin 

    insert into #Ref(i ,FileName)
    select @pagecount , @File_name
    set @pagecount = @pagecount+ 1
end


--select * from #Ref
go


update #Ref 
set IsValue = 1 
where i in (select i from #Ref cross join Table2
where i >=from_page and i <= to_page)  ----  update the pages which are     available 


declare @File_name char(1) , @TotalPages int , @pagecount int , @isVal int =     2


select @TotalPages = TotalPages , @pagecount = 1 from Table1 

while (@pagecount <= @TotalPages)
begin 

  if exists( select * from #Ref where i = @pagecount and IsValue is not     null)
  begin 
   set @isVal = @isVal + 1 
  end 

  update  #Ref
  set IsValue = @isVal
  where i = @pagecount
  and IsValue is null 


  set @pagecount = @pagecount + 1 

end




select FileName ,MIN(i)from_page , MAX(i) to_page  from #Ref
where IsValue <>1
group by FileName ,IsValue
```